# How do I change the thickness of a shape's outline on a tkinter canvas in Python?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Is there a way to increase or decrease the thickness of a shape's outline on a tkinter canvas? If so, how do I do it?

Here's some code that can be used as an example. How could the rectangle's outline width be changed?

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=350)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150, fill='blue')

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use option width

=^..^=

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=350)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150, width=0, fill='blue')
root.mainloop()
```